# 2012 Animax anime where a high school boy's whole school including her girlfriend memories are erased by the government

Tags: story-identification, anime

In the first episode a high school boy, his girlfriend, and a friend are shown, and after that the government comes to capture him. He is saved by his people. The government erased the memory of his whole school. Years later, he appears in a broadcast to the whole country, and upon seeing him, his girlfriend and the rest of his memory comes back.His girlfriend works for government now and has a new boyfriend who have long hair.

I'm not sure in which year I watched it was between 2010-2012

Comment: If you could, please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question to find some prompts to provide more details that you can edit into your question. Like, did you watch this in 2012? Are you certain that was when it was released? And in what country?

Comment: It is not please teacher and MC is the highschool boy

Comment: Did you get a chance to check out the two links above to elicit further details?

Comment: Does the memory of him come back to his girlfriend on the broadcast? Or is it his memory, including of her, that comes back? I'm not certain how that sentence works. And who are "his people"? Aliens? Foreigners? Magic community? Werewolves? Fae folk?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, its not please teacher.

Comment: I recognize that. :) However, my other questions still stand. I'm not certain whose memories got wiped, or who "his people" are. If you don't know, that's alright too, but I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: Yes, memory of him come back to his girlfriend during broadcast.